# display tooltip on button focus in blackberry

Tags: blackberry-simulator

Can anybody tell me how to display ToolTip on blackberry on button focus listener? I am using blackberry 6.0. I have tried Status.show() method. but it display huge tool tip between of the screen. Any other way to display tooltip which display nearby of the field.

Answer (score 0):

well, the best way i would suggest is, create a custom labelfield with a arrow kind of a bg image , on button focus listner , show the labelfield with a timer running , and remove the labelfield after sometime, dont know if this is what u r asking for,, we try the same approach in our project.

Comment: Hey ajit thanks for reply. can i get an example or any link similar to this.

Comment: I have used this http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Problem-with-Tooltip/td-p/102847 and its working fine.